Why do let variables have problems with initialization?


let f = f;




ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'f' before initialization

I understand that variable declaration proceeds in three steps.

Declaration
initialization
Assignment

So why does the above code produce a reference error?

Declaration (Temporal Dead Zone)


let f = f; Reach declaration statement 
let f = undefined; //initialization
let f = f; //Why did a reference error occur?

I read the book but there is no answer

Why would you expect that to work? Does it make sense to initialize a variable with its own value (that has not been initialized)?

I would like to know why it is not initialized because I think there is no problem if it goes through the steps of initializing it to undefined and assigning a value.

TL;DR: TDZ lasts until the variable is fully declared. Until the point of the semicolon of let f = f; statement, it still is variable f's TDZ. That's why it shows the Reference Error on the second f.

Thank you!! I got a lot of help from the links and comments you posted!!
let f = 6;

let f = undefined; //After releasing TDZ
undefined initialization
f = 6; //Assignment
It is not executed through the steps, but is initialized directly with let f = 6. thank you!!


The whole of let f = f; is the declaration. So when f needs to be read for the declaration of f, then f is not yet declared because it's still reliant on f. I don't even see why you'd believe let f = f; is valid code - even if it worked the way you expected it, surely it'd mean that something is wrong. There is no meaning to assigning nothing to f when declaring it. The only reasonable way you'd get that code is if it was a typo, e.g., it was supposed to be let f = g; or similar. There is never a reason why let f = f; should be valid.

I was curious how it worked. I wanted to know whether the initialization only refers to undefined assignments or also includes value assignments.-_-

The main confusion for OP is the difference between let f; f = f; and let f = f; IMO. While the first one is valid since the reference of f happens after the variable f is declared, even without a value. Since it happens after the declaration (let f; statement). However the second one is a single statement, which the reference is not ready yet when f is referred.
